# Удаление строки статического массива

Tags: c++, c, массивы, матрицы

Я работаю со статической матрицей, сначала задаю число строк и столбцов (допустим 1000х1000), а затем использую какую-то подматрицу. Задача состоит в том, чтобы удалить первую строку массива. Я думал над тем, чтобы переопределить указатель с первой строки на вторую, но не совсем понимаю, как это можно сделать. Есть еще вариант сдвинуть каждую строку вверх на одну, но этот способ мне кажется неэффективным, есть ли какие-то разумные решения?

Answer (score 5):

"Сдвинуть указатель" можно, хотя это будет несколько через... вобщем, не самым прямым путем.

В С++ проще всего воспользоваться ссылкой:

```
int m[5][5] =
{
    { 1,2,3,4,5},
    { 6,7,8,9,10},
    { 11,12,13,14,15},
    { 16,17,18,19,20},
    { 21,22,23,24,25}
};

typedef int reduced_matrix[4][5];

reduced_matrix& r = *(reduced_matrix*)(m+1);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        cout << r[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

(Полный текст программы - [тут](https://ideone.com/cPPfP9).) Но почему бы вам не воспользоваться тем же динамическим массивом, или, еще лучше - векторами? Так вы получите куда более гибкое решение.

В случае C так просто подменить матрицу мне не удалось, пришлось использовать лишний уровень косвенности -

```
typedef int reduced_matrix[4][5];
reduced_matrix * r = (reduced_matrix*)(m+1);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        printf("%2d  ",(*r)[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Однако нет никаких проблем передать такую смещенную матрицу в функцию:

```
void out_matrix(int r[4][5])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            printf("%2d  ",r[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

...

out_matrix(m+1);
```

(Полный код [тут](https://ideone.com/EXbQ9J).)

Comment: Можно ли где-то прочитать подробнее про конструкцию?

`typedef int reduced_matrix[4][5];
reduced_matrix& r = *(reduced_matrix*)(m+1);`

Не очень понятно, почему просто нельзя вернуть ссылку на m + 1 и можно ли обойти без typedef?

Comment: Тут две конструкции :) - что именно вас интересует? Обойтись без `typedef` можно, только зачем? Будет многословно. Хотите просто вернуть ссылку на `m+1` - верните, без вопросов. В прямом смысле без вопросов - если вы знаете, как делать, то не надо спрашивать...